# Case sensitive sorting with capitals last

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort a List< string> case sensitive with capitals last, i.e. in the order

a,aBC,b,bXY,c,A,Ax,B,C,...

I have tried

```
Comparison<string> c = (string x1,string x2) => StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x1,x2);
list.Sort(c);
```

but it returns

A,Ax,B,C,a,aBC,b,bXY,c,...

Is there any predefined method to do this, or will I need to fiddle something together myself?

**Edit:** Since "capitals last" seems difficult enough I have spared numbers for the moment.

Comment: dirty hack: 1) replace lowercase to uppercase and vice versa. 2) sort as you did. 3) execute 1 again.

Comment: @JohnTortugo: Dirty or not, that's a damn good idea!

Comment: @JohnTortugo lel thats a good idea (thumbs up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have opted for the suggestion by @JohnTortugo. Thanks John, incredibly simple idea, short and easy to implement!

1. Swap upper and lower case in a string by XOR'ing 0x20 with each byte (ASCII coding assumed):

   ```
   static string swapUpperLower(string s)
   {
       return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s).Select(c => (byte)(c^0x20)).ToArray());
   }
   ```
2. Swap case for every string in the list before and after sorting

   ```
       Comparison<string> c = (string x1,string x2) => StringComparer.Ordinal.Compare(x1,x2);

       sl = sl.Select(s => swapUpperLower(s)).ToList();
       sl.Sort(c);
       sl = sl.Select(s => swapUpperLower(s)).ToList();
   ```

Result:

a
aBC
b
bXY
c
A
Ax
B
C

Comment: Ya its really simple lel, i was also making this :v

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("aBcDEf");
        var result = ascii.OrderByDescending(b => b).ToList();
        string converted = string.Empty;
        foreach(var c in result)
        {
            converted += Char.ConvertFromUtf32(c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(converted);
```

[image]

Comment: That's also capitals first, which is not what I want. I want capitals last, like the title says.

Comment: It is still designed for single characters, not a list of strings.

Comment: create array of string and use same foreach string..simple enough 

Comment: can you explain _Um, well, no..._

Comment: Sorting strings is not at all the same as sorting characters in a string.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this lengthy code It works Like A Charm**

```
public static List<String> CustomSort(List<String> ls)
    {

        ls.Sort();
        List<String> Oint = new List<String>();
        List<String> Ocap = new List<String>();
        List<String> Osma = new List<String>();

        foreach(string s in ls)
        {
            int n;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(s, out n);
            if(isNumeric)
            {
                Oint.Add(s);
            }
            else if (char.IsUpper(s[0]))
            {
                Ocap.Add(s);
            }
            else if (!char.IsUpper(s[0]))
            {
                Osma.Add(s);
            }
        }

        var r1 = Oint.Concat(Osma).Concat(Ocap);

        List<String> com = r1.ToList();
        return com;

    }
```

**Then Call it Like**

```
List<String> ls = new List<String>();
            ls.Add("1");
            ls.Add("Cdsd");
            ls.Add("BCCd");
            ls.Add("ADDD");
            ls.Add("3");
            ls.Add("2");
            ls.Add("aDFD");
            ls.Add("cSS");
            ls.Add("b");
        List<String> cuz = CustomSort(ls);
        foreach(String s in cuz)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

You can Try This Code [here](http://rextester.com/DIEEU84082)

Comment: I am afraid, this will not work because you are just taking single characters into account. What about "Aaaaa" versus "aaaAA" or "aaAaa" versus "aaa12"?

Comment: It must work, if you take Aaaaa vs aaaAA then aaAaa will come first

Comment: btw in aaAaa and aaa12 which one you want to come first?

Comment: aaa12 comes before aaAaa because A is the first difference and it should succeed a.

Comment: Ya i just tried all type of string, i verified it aaa12 will come first

Comment: Its true that i take one char at account but i already sort list by default method and then resort list, thats why the code will work for those strings too

Comment: Nope Its Not Accident !

Comment: Well just provide me versus example of string that doesnt work with code and i am willing to edit my code to improve it :D

Comment: OooooH Bro, ig i just found a loophole, can you tell me what should come first between A and Aaaa

Comment: {"BaBgd","BaBgC"}, BaBgd should come first but your code results in BaBgC first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166443/discussion-between-agent-orange-and-oliver).